# How do I delete ssh keygen for user?

Tags: linux, git, atlassian-sourcetree, ssh-keygen

I have accidentally created a kengen for a user that does not exist. The command was `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >> keydir/jpeck.pub` but actually... I didn't mean to do that.

I have already deleted the file using `rm jpeck.pub` and it is certainly gone. However, when I try to push a commit using SourceTree I get the following error;

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 

Pushing to ssh://git@sandbox.dev:2222/dashboard.git

W access for dashboard DENIED to jpeck

(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

The next message `Your commit succeeded but your push failed. To retry your push, use the Push toolbar button.`

I have created a keygen for the CORRECT username. And I can't see what else I need to do.. I have tried `sudo service apache2 restart` but that had no effect. I am a beginner with installing git but also it was a silly mistake to make - I am very tired today.

Comment: It seems to think jpeck is a user that does exist. "...dashboard DENIED to jpeck". Do you have jpeck configured as a user somewhere in SourceTree?

Comment: @GrahamPerks Definitely not! Through the front-end I never set up a jpeck user. The only time I typed jpeck was when I did it in the line above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I hadn't actually committed and pushed the changes to git. These commands did it;

```
git commit -a -m "Adding gitweb permissions"
git push
```

Once I did that, I got a message about how the jpeck keygen file had been deleted in git. Then when I tried to use SourceTree, as before, it worked with no errors.